# How to create an MS Access query that inserts an ID value into another table based on the table name in a separate table?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database with three tables: "requests", "table1", and "table2". Both "table1" and "table1" have a single attribute named "ID" set as short text. The "requests" table has two attributes: "ID" and "table_name". The "table_name" attribute can have values "table1" and "table2". I need help find a way (query/button in form...) in MS Access that takes the "table_name" attribute from the "requests" table and inserts the "ID" value into the table with the same name as the value of the "table_name" attribute. Ideally something like a for loop that could work with more than 2 tables.

I tried to create a VBA function (activated by button in form). However, it didn't work, and the "ID" values were not inserted into the appropriate tables ("table1" and "table2"). I am not sure where is mistake in this code or if there is some other method?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command0_Click()
    UpdateTables
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateTables()
Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    strSQL = "SELECT ID, table_name FROM requests;"
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    While Not rs.EOF
        If rs!table_name = "table1" Then
            db.Execute "INSERT INTO table1 (ID) VALUES ('" & rs!ID & "');"
        ElseIf rs!table_name = "table2" Then
            db.Execute "INSERT INTO table2 (ID) VALUES ('" & rs!ID & "');"
        End If
        
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code and try to see where it was going wrong?

Comment: If there are no NULL records for `table_name` then you could use `db.Execute "INSERT INTO " & rs!table_name & "(ID) VALUES ('" & rs!ID & "');"`